# Partial fraction expansion of rational functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I've been trying to read about partial fraction expansion of rational function.

Is the following statement equivalent to the uniqueness+existence of partial function expansion?:

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an algebraically closed field and let $D=\{\frac{p}{q}~:~p,q\in\mathbb{F}[x],~\deg(p)\leq\deg(q)\}$. Consider $D$ as a linear space above $\mathbb{F}$. Then the set $\{(x-a)^{n}~:~a\in\mathbb{F},~n\leq0\}$ is a basis for $D$.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: We tend to say "as a vector space over $\mathbb F$" rather than "as a linear space above $\mathbb F$."  But yes, this is correct.